# Add new Calculated column; Start_DateTime plus duration (Time) as End_datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, calculated-columns

SQL Server Agent Jobs; In msdb you have dbo.sysjobhistory who gives you Run_date and Run_time as type INT which easily can be converted to Start_Datetime with dbo.agent_datetime. I get: 2018-05-17 01:13:09.240

Run_duration is INT as well. I use

```
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(jh.run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS'Time_HH:MM:SS'
```

I get 27:31:20

I want to calculate a new column as `End_datetime`. (i.e Start_datetime  + Run_duration)  My jobs are running more than 24h etc so date can go into the next day as well.

Where to start? After conversion or start with the original `INT` columns

```
Run_date, Run_time, Run_duration
```

Simplest script would be most helpful.

Comment: OutPut is without seconds  End_date 2016-09-04 00:00:28.000
seconds 28

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the "duration" as `datetime`, then just sum it to your `start_date`

```
select  dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) START_TIME,
        STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') DURATION,
        CONVERT(datetime, dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time)) +
        CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') ) AS END_TIME

from sysjobhistory
```

Output:

> ```
> START_TIME              DURATION END_TIME
> ----------------------- -------- -----------------------
> 2017-06-11 04:00:01.000 01:05:33 2017-06-11 05:05:34.000
> 2017-06-18 04:00:00.000 01:05:30 2017-06-18 05:05:30.000
> 2017-06-18 04:00:00.000 01:05:30 2017-06-18 05:05:30.000
>
> 2018-01-28 04:00:00.000 02:15:07 2018-01-28 06:15:07.000
> 2018-01-28 04:00:00.000 02:15:07 2018-01-28 06:15:07.000
> 2018-02-04 04:00:00.000 02:14:29 2018-02-04 06:14:29.000
> 2018-02-04 04:00:00.000 02:14:30 2018-02-04 06:14:30.000
> 2018-02-11 04:00:01.000 02:18:47 2018-02-11 06:18:48.000
> 2018-02-11 04:00:00.000 02:18:48 2018-02-11 06:18:48.000
> 2018-02-18 04:00:01.000 02:18:18 2018-02-18 06:18:19.000
> ```

Comment: Just addedd  CONVERT(datetime, dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time)) +
        CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') ) AS END_TIME and workd fine!

Comment: @Michael That's good :) Please dont forget to accept it as answer.

Comment: Does your solution cover when a job i s running more than 2h? see discussion here at the bottom in on page [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014]

Answer (score 2):

Convert duration into seconds and perform `Dateadd`

```
 SELECT convert(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), run_date))
        ,run_duration % 100 seconds
        ,DATEADD(ss, (run_duration % 100), convert(DATETIME, convert(VARCHAR(10), run_date))) 
              End_date
    FROM dbo.sysjobhistory
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemd to be working easier for me

```
    , DATEADD(SECOND, run_duration / 10000 * 3600 + run_duration % 10000 / 100 * 60 + run_duration % 100, 
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(jh.run_date, jh.run_time)) AS End_DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you different ways to convert the `run_date` and `run_time` in `sysjobhistory`:

```
SELECT run_date,
           SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) AS "RunDate1",
           STUFF(STUFF(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-') AS "RunDate2",
           run_time,
           SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 2) AS "RunTime1",
           STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS "RunTime2",
           dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS "DateTimeDerived",
           CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 2) AS DATETIME) AS "RunDateTime1",
           CAST(STUFF(STUFF(CAST(run_date AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-') + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME) AS "RunDateTime2"
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).